# Unity 2D Object not Moving while using GetKey and tranform.position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector, keycode

Got a problem with my code (on Unity 2D).

I'm trying to make a PacMan like for my class, and my PacMan doesn't want to move at all.
He's animated but he's not moving.

```
    public class PacmanMove : MonoBehaviour {
    public float speed = 0.4f;
    Vector2 dest = Vector2.zero;

    void Start() {
        dest = transform.position;
    }

    void FixedUpdate() {
        // Move closer to Destination
        Vector2 p = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, dest, speed);
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().MovePosition(p);

        // Check for Input if not moving
        if ((Vector2)transform.position == dest) {
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow) && valid(Vector2.up))
                dest = (Vector2)transform.position + Vector2.up;
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow) && valid(Vector2.right))
                dest = (Vector2)transform.position + Vector2.right;
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow) && valid(-Vector2.up))
                dest = (Vector2)transform.position - Vector2.up;
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow) && valid(-Vector2.right))
                dest = (Vector2)transform.position - Vector2.right;
        }
    }

    bool valid(Vector2 dir) {
        // Cast Line from 'next to Pac-Man' to 'Pac-Man'
        Vector2 pos = transform.position;
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Linecast(pos + dir, pos);
        return (hit.collider == GetComponent<Collider2D>());
    }
}
```

Please help me :)

Comment: You should remove "GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>()" from your FixedUpdate and get the Rigidbody only once in your Start and store it in a member

Comment: What debugging did you do. As a float comparison of dest and position can be basically the same but not exactly the same in which case it wont check your input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have to use physics, you can use this.

```
void FixedUpdate() {
        

        // Check for Input if not moving
        if ((Vector2)transform.position == dest) {
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow) && valid(Vector2.up))
                dest = (Vector2)transform.position + Vector2.up;
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow) && valid(Vector2.right))
                dest = (Vector2)transform.position + Vector2.right;
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow) && valid(-Vector2.up))
                dest = (Vector2)transform.position - Vector2.up;
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow) && valid(-Vector2.right))
                dest = (Vector2)transform.position - Vector2.right;
        }
        else
        {
            // Move closer to Destination
            transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, dest, speed);
        }
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem wasn't in the code, it was on my Object's configuration
If you have the same problem, check out if your Object's gravity is on 0 :)